# What's causing an infinite loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, wp-reset-postdata

I have to use parent posts as categories.

So I'm checking if current post has childs and show them or else show te content.

I'm trying like this (in single-practice.php):

```
<?php
$has_children = false;
$children = get_children(
    array(
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
    )
);
wp_reset_postdata();
if ( ! empty($children) ) {
    $has_children = true;
}

if ($has_children) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'practice',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'paged' => false
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    /* var_dump($query); */

    ?>
    <div class="services">
        <div data-isotope-options='{"itemSelector" : ".item","layoutMode" : "masonry","transitionDuration":"0.7s","masonry" : {"columnWidth":".item"}}' class="grid isotope clearfix portfolio-holder"> 

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        ?>      
        <div class="item item-col col-1 ">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service-item">
                <span class="overlay"></span>
                <figure><img width="320" height="305" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID())); ?>" class="attachment-320x305-center-center size-320x305-center-center wp-post-image" alt="" /></figure>
                <span class="service-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?></div>
    </div><!--/ .entry-box--><?php 

} else {
    /* this is the original template code. */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;

    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Previous page', 'hickshynson' ) . '</span>',
        'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Next page', 'hickshynson' ) . '</span>',
        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Page', 'hickshynson' ) . ' </span>'
    ) );


    the_content();

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before'      => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'hickshynson' ),
        'after'       => '</div>',
        'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
        'link_after'  => '</span>',
    ) );
}
?>
```

Note that the else is the same code that was in the template before I added the if.

For some reason, this code never finishes **if the current post does not  have children**.. so I cannot see the page fully loaded,

What might be causing this? I'm using `wp_reset_postadata()` but the infinite loop still there,

Any  idea?

-this is the $args how registered the post type-

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => hh_get_labels(
        __( 'Area', 'hh_app_textdomain' ),
        __( 'Areas', 'hh_app_textdomain' )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'archive' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => self::$slug ),
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio'
);
```

-UPDATE-

By removing this block

```
/* this is the original template code. */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
```

The problem is no longer there. That's ok because `the_content()` has all I need, but still curious. Any thoughts?

Comment: I took your code, used it on `page.php`, and changed `'post_type' => 'page',` and it worked as expected. Are you sure it's an infinite loop and not just a fatal php error? What does your error log say? Do you have `WP_DEBUG` on?

Comment: Also does your 'practice' post type have `hierarchical` and `page-attributes` properly set?

Comment: @DavidSword I edited the question with the args from register_postype. And that's my guess. i don't get any errors. but the page is loading forever..